# Ranking / Finding Dates

Tags: oracle, date, rank

I have these records:

```
PHOT    1/16/2017   20170118    0.01
PHOT    1/16/2017   20170117    0.0103
PHOT    1/16/2017   20170116    0.0101
PHOT    1/16/2017   20170115    0.0101
PHOT    1/16/2017   20170114    0.0105
.
.
.
MSRT    12/31/2016  20170327    0.855
MSRT    12/31/2016  20170324    0.87
MSRT    12/31/2016  20170323    0.87
MSRT    12/31/2016  20170322    0.88
MSRT    12/31/2016  20170321    0.89
.
.
.
```

Basically I need the record with the closest date in column 3 which is <= the date in column 2.

It should be partitioned by column 1.I only need 1 record, that being the one that has the closed column 2 date to column 1 date.

Can this be done with some DENSE_RANK?  Or should I be using ROW_NUMBER?

Comment: What are the datatypes of the column2 and 3?

Comment: DENSE_RANK and ROW_NUMBER will produce the same result if there are no duplicates for (column1, column3). If there ARE duplicates, your problem is not fully specified: if, for the same string in column1, you have two or more rows tied for "closest date" in column3, which should be selected? (Or all of them?) This is where either DENSE_RANK or ROW_NUMBER will be the right choice; which is the right choice depends on your business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should help:

```
 Select * from (
 select row_number() over (partition by t.col1 order by      
 abs(t.col2-to_date(t.col3, 'yyyymmdd'))) rw, t.*
 From tbl t where t.col2 >= to_date(t.col3, 'yyyymmdd')) where rw = 1;
```

Explanation:

The inner query use the to_date function on the col3 for format the date to the same pattern like col2.

Then we can compare it to col2 in the where clause. Next, we rank the absolute space between those two columns (again with to_date) for each col1 (partition by col1, order by abs).

Finally, we take the top row for each col1 group (rw=1).

Note that if you are using dense_ranke, it can create several rows for each col1, because if you have 2 rows with the same absolute value - the dense_ranke will rank them the same number (let's say -1), and then you can get few rows for each column. Row_number always will give unique rank for each row.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: true. Now explanation exist. Thank you.